# pinia store installed after state call

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

I'm building a vuejs 3 application with composition API.

I have 2 stores: a `userStore` for holding userid, jwt and similar stuff (that gets populated upon login) and a `dataStore` that holds data related to the user (populated when user does operations).

When a user logs in successfully, she is redirected to a page containing user data.

The login page uses the userStore and the data page uses the dataStore. The dataStore needs the user's id and jwt.

This method is called upon login:

```js
const submitlogin = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await postData.post('/user/a/login', {
      email: form.email,
      password: form.password,
    })
    if (response) {
      userStore.loggedIn = true
      // first get the jwt
      userStore.getJWT()
      // then go to the next page where jwt is required
      router.push({
        name: 'operation',
        params: { sens: 'depense', quand: 'maintenant' },
      })
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log (error)
  }
}
```

I [import](https://pinia.vuejs.org/cookbook/composing-stores.html#nested-stores) the userStore into the dataStore:

```js
// dataStore
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import { useUserStore } from '@/stores/userStore.js'

actions: {
    async getAccounts(id, month, year) {
      const user = useUserStore
      // getData is an [axios create function][1]
      getData.defaults.headers.common['__authorization__'] = user.jwt
      getData.get(`/use/b/comptes/${id}/${month}/${year}`).then((response) => {
     // cut because irrelevant here
     }
```

Then, on the first after login:

```js
// data view
import { useUserStore } from '../stores/userStore'
import { useDataStore } from '@/stores/dataStore'

const dataStore = useDataStore()
const userStore = useUserStore()

onMounted(() => {
  dataStore.getAccounts()
})
```

However, the autorization header is `undefined` only at this first call. If I further navigated to other views where I import the dataStore `user.jwt` is defined.

It seems that the dataStore is mounted correclty, but its state isn't available yet at the moment I call it.

Comment: When do you set the `user.jwt`. Are you sure that it is settled before your first call of  `dataStore.getAccounts()`?

Comment: `userStore.getJWT()` is an async function or it is synchronous?

Comment: async. I solved this. I have answered my own question.

Answer (score 2):

Solved!
I changed the `dataStore` so that userStore is defined not within the function, but right after import.
Kind of logical since the getAccounts function is async, so the definition of user.jwt also was.

```js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import { getData } from '@/composables/useApi'
import { sumBy } from 'lodash'
import { useUserStore } from '@/stores/userStore.js'
// put this here, not within the async action !
const userStore = useUserStore()

  actions: {
    async getAccounts(id, month, year) {
      getData.defaults.headers.common['__authorization__'] = userStore.jwt
      getData.get(`/use/b/comptes/${id}/${month}/${year}`).then((response) => {
// cut because irrelevant here
}
```